# Capacitor / Ionic / Vue Local Notification eventlistener

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, event-handling, capacitor, localnotification

I'm trying to get Local Notifications working in an Ionic Vue app (using capacitor).

I did get scheduling notifications working, but now i want to listen to clicks on the notification.

in main.js I bind LocalNotifications to this.$LocalNotifications:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { LocalNotifications } = Plugins;

Vue.prototype.$LocalNotifications = LocalNotifications;
```

in my Root component App I have this:

```
created() {
console.log('Created!')
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
      console.log('ready');
       this.$LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationReceived', (notification) => {
          console.log('Notification action received', notification);
        });
    }, false);
}
```

When I build and run on the ios-emulator, i get the following output in my log:

```
APP ACTIVE
To Native Cordova ->  Badge load Badge1248600129 ["options": []]
⚡️  [log] - onscript loading complete
To Native Cordova ->  Device getDeviceInfo Device1248600130 ["options": []]
⚡️  To Native ->  Storage get 90127150
⚡️  TO JS {"value":null}
⚡️  [log] - Created!
To Native Cordova ->  LocalNotification launch LocalNotification1248600131 ["options": []]
To Native Cordova ->  LocalNotification ready INVALID ["options": []]
⚡️  To Native ->  LocalNotifications addListener ⚡️  [log] - ready
90127151
⚡️  WebView loaded
⚡️  To Native ->  App addListener 90127152
```

When I schedule a Notification, the notification does show up, but I think something doesn't go quite well when i'm adding the listener:

```
INVALID ["options":[]]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?
Or does anyone have a code example of working notifications in an Ionic Vue app?

Kind regards,

Bram

Comment: have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: I ended up using this package in main.js:   import {LocalNotifications} from '@ionic-native/local-notifications'  and in the beforeCreate hook I subscribe to clicks: LocalNotifications.on('click').subscribe((x) => {...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up:

You should use `localNotificationActionPerformed` instead of `localNotificationReceived`. The latter is called when notifications are displayed, while the other is listening to actions performed on a notification (as it's stated in the [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications#addlistenerlocalnotificationreceived)), that of course includes clicking / tapping on it.
So your code would look like this:

```
this.$LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationActionPerformed', (notification) => {
  console.log('Notification action received', notification.actionId);
});
```

...which would output "tap". Since you did write 'Notification action received', I assume you wanted to get the action, so I added *.actionId* after 'notification', which only by itself would be logged as [object Object] or as the object tree.

You also asked for code example, so here it comes:

```
// 1.
import { LocalNotifications } from '@capacitor/local-notifications';

// 2.
await LocalNotifications.requestPermissions();

// 3.
await LocalNotifications.registerActionTypes({
  types: [
    {
      id: 'your_choice',
      actions: [
        {
          id: 'dismiss',
          title: 'Dismiss',
          destructive: true
        },
        {
          id: 'open',
          title: 'Open app'
        },
        {
          id: 'respond',
          title: 'Respond',
          input: true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});

// 4.
LocalNotifications.schedule({
  notifications: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Sample title',
      body: 'Sample body',
      actionTypeId: 'your_choice'
    }
  ]
});

// 5.
LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationActionPerformed', (notification) => {
  console.log(`Notification ${notification.notification.title} was ${notification.actionId}ed.`);
});
```

1: Since your question, [plugins have been placed into their own npm packages](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#official-plugins), so one needs to install @capacitor/local-notifications and import from there.

2: You should make sure that notifications are allowed, ask for permissions if needed.

3: Tapping was your question's topic, but you can define a lot more than that.

4: This is how you actually create & send a notification at once.

5: Logs "Notification Sample title was *taped* / *opened* / *dismissed* / *responded*.", according to the given action (but not always according to grammar).

Finally, if someone's just getting into local notifications, check out the [really nice documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications) on what else (a whole lot more!) can be done and also [watching this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bww4a4B43tM) might give one a head start. At least that's what I did.